# How to join collections on nosqlbooster so that I can run $avg query on it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, average

I have two collections in my database with field names in the documents that are the same. I need to join these collections and then sum the values of the common field names and finally find the average as my output.

This is an example of a document in the first collection

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63074885ff3acbe0d63d7686"),
    
"year" : "2020",
    
"energy_products" : "Other Energy Products",
    
"sub_products" : "Other Energy Products",
    
"value_ktoe" : "70.4"
},
```

This is an example of a document in the second collection

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("63074882ff3acbe0d63c391a"),

"year" : "2020",

"energy_products" : "Petroleum Products",

"sub_products" : "Other Petroleum Products",

"value_ktoe" : "10633.7"
},
```

So I need to join the collections and sum up all the values in the energy_products and the sub_products part and then find the average.

The output needs to look something like this

```json
    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : {
            "energy_products" : "Petroleum Products"
        },
        "avg" : 18312.05625
    },
```

```json
    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : {
            "sub_products" : "Jet Fuel Kerosene"
        },
        "avg" : 4253.884375
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a `$unionWith` to "merge" the 2 collections. Perform a simple `$group` to get the `$avg` you need.

```js
db.coll1.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "energy_products": "$energy_products"
      },
      "avg": {
        "$avg": {
          "$toDouble": "$value_ktoe"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "coll2",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "sub_products": "$sub_products"
            },
            "avg": {
              "$avg": {
                "$toDouble": "$value_ktoe"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kEdgkPSVxF2)